# Angular 7 not sending HttpClient POST request - instead dying with "Unknown Error"

Tags: angular, typescript, rest, angular-httpclient

**EDIT3: SOLUTION after hours:**
Firefox extension uBlock blocked the request (probably because it contained *adverts*)
Lesson learned: always check in a private tab!

**I Really run out of ideas and appreciate every bit of advice :)**

**EDIT:**
For intuitivity:
Im sending two POST requests
**/api/adverts/search which does not even show up in Firefox network tab.**
and
**/api/marketplacecategories/get which returns successfull with 200**

**EDIT2:**
The same request from a fresh angular app works

Sending the request:

```
  let options = {
     'headers' : {
        'accept': 'application/json'
     }
  }
  let data = new FormData()
  this.http.post("/api/adverts/search",data, options)
  .subscribe(
     data => {
        console.log("success")
        console.log(data)
     }
  );
```

Angular is not sending the request:

[image]

But instead giving me an error in the js console:

[image]

Meanwhile the other POST request to the same api is working just fine.

Postman to the same url works just fine:

[image]

CORS headers are set by server globally and work just fine for the other successfull request:

[image]

Does anyone have the slightest idea?
Im quite desperate :D

Comment: Can you check the server logs?

Comment: @PhilippMeissner nginx access.log shows all other requests (incl. the other POST but not api/adverts/search :) error.log shows no errors :(

Comment: From your screenshot, I can see that you're doing a `POST` request in Postman whereas your angular-app does a `GET` request (At least judging from the screenshot that displays the error, not the actual code.

Comment: Also it looks that the error is on the backend rather than the FE, considering the BE answers with a `status 200` but the actual content is not what you expect. So you should go down that path, rather than checking the frontend (my two cents).

Comment: @PhilippMeissner there are two requests being done: api/adverts/search and /api/marketplacecategories/get the api/adverts/search is not even being sent / stated in firefox network tab. The POST request /api/marketplacecategories/get works just fine :)

Comment: @PhilippMeissner the status 200 is for the POST request /api/marketplacecategories/get the other one does not even show up.

Comment: Compare the headers between postman and the request from your app. Make them the same and see if it works.

Comment: @NicholasK https://pasteboard.co/IstzO0Y.png

Comment: From that screenshot it looks like you aren't adding any additional headers while hitting the POST api via postman. Can you try this from angular `this.http.post("/api/adverts/search", {}, options)`? If that didn't work try it by passing in `null` as the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firefox uBlock Origin extension blocked the request**
probably because it contained *adverts*.

Lesson learned: always check in a private tab!

Solved.

Thank you all very much for your time and advice!

Comment: I can't tell how often that screwed me over already :D
We're rewriting all routes containing `ads` or `adv` automatically to `das` and `avd`. Maybe such a system might be of use for you as well.

Comment: Good to know I´m not the only one falling into that trap ^^ Thank you very much for your condolence :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the full url like:

```
this.http.post("http://192.168.56.11:2503/api/adverts/search",data, options)
```

You should store the common port in environment.ts

`apiUrl: "http://192.168.56.11:2503"`

and then,

```
this.http.post(`${environment.apiUrl}/api/adverts/search`,data, options)
```

Comment: This is what I did in the first place. The code above is me narrowing down to the error :) Using te full url as endpoint produces exactly the same behaviour.

Comment: Are you using httpClient? Show your constructor once

Comment: Why are u using `let data = new FormData()`, what data do you need to pass?

Comment: Later (actually it was already working for a long time -.-) I will pass FormData but for the tests I just did it so I wouldnt pass nullstuff etc.